# Wrong text when isTextSelectable

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a custom view which derives from LinearLayout and which inflates the following xml in the constructor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:text="Value" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This view is contained twice (or more times) in my Activity. I also replace the strings "Title" and "Value" in the constructor of the view, so they might be "title1"/"value1" and "title2"/"value2" for the two instances of the view.

I thought this was working as expected until I rotated my phone (I also need to make sure the activity get's destroyed in this process). After recreating the Activity, the first value text is "value2" instead of "value1"!

I tracked the problem down that it comes from the textIsSelectable. When I removed that attribute, it work's fine.

I am targeting API level 14, the attribute is only part of my layout-v14 folder. It's the same if I set the attribute programmatically.

Did anybody else experience this? Do you know any way around this problem??

Note that I'm working with Mono for Android - not sure if this is a bug there?

Comment: Why don't you just save the state when the device rotate and re-load it when it is done?